# How to include form validation in a separate page react.js semantic ui

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

In the semantic ui documentation it states that you can validate a file using full validation settings. I have created a separate file, that handles the validation.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function() {


$('.booking')
    .form({
        fields: {
            fromCountry: {
                identifier: "fromCountry",
                rules: [
                    {
                        type: "empty",
                        prompt: "Please enter your name"
                    }
                ]

            }

        }
    })
```

});

I have imported this validation file into my other react js files that need validation. However, it states that form is not a function. What library does form belong to?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#types-form.

You can also use above code but first you have to check that script is loaded before execution of the above code and you have to move code to componentDidMount life cycle method.

Comment: thanks. How would you move the code into the componentDidMount life cycle method? I have included the the validate file as an import in the react.js files that require validation. For example, in a form component in the import section I have placed       import "../Common/Validate";

Comment: move this code 

`componentDidMount(){
$('.booking')
    .form({
        fields: {
            fromCountry: {
                identifier: "fromCountry",
                rules: [
                    {
                        type: "empty",
                        prompt: "Please enter your name"
                    }
                ]

            }

        }
    })
}`